# Use Azure Function of (HttpTrigger – C#) in Add Azure Logic App

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I am writing an Azure function (HttpTrigger – C#) that contains some statements that insert into Azure SQL Server. I followed this tutorial.

I want to use it in Azure Logic App. But it does not allow to add this type of function as an action. 
Azure Logic App allows to add only those functions that are or Generic Webhook type. But Database storing support is available in (HttpTrigger – C#) type functions.
Is there a way to call (HttpTrigger – C#) from another function that is already added in Azure Logic App.

Is there another better way to achieve it ?

Comment: As such if your azure function app is a generic webhook app you can call them from logic app .Functions that use these templates are automatically discovered and listed in the Logic Apps designer under Azure Functions in my region.Or if it is  okay to connect to the db and insert data from the logic app itself then you can try the sql connector for logic apps.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to change the mode to Webhook and the webhook type to generic JSON for your function.

The ability to communicate with SQL Azure is not limited to functions using HTTP Triggers, so you should be able to use essentially the same logic and expose the function in a way that would be easily consumable from Logic Apps.

Answer (score 1):

We're working on supporting HTTPTrigger type functions, it should be available soon. In the meantime, you should be able to use HTTP action to trigger those functions. With this workaround, you will need to handle the authentication yourself.